# Application based(which is used) OpenMPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, openmpi

Please help me to find some working application which is using openmpi. I need any name of application which have widely/worldwide usage and based on openmpi (using it). At least the name of that kind application will be enough.

Thanks

Comment: How about [gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org). From `apt-cache rdepends libopenmpi1.3` on Debian system, which lists quite a lot.

Comment: Applications are written to the MPI standard, not a particular implementation of MPI, of which Open MPI is but one.  If you have misunderstood what Open MPI is, i.e. confused it with the MPI standard, then please submit a new question that is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) is an implementation of [MPI](http://www.mpi-forum.org/). Applications are written using MPI (i.e. the code calls MPI routines), and they can be compiled/run using any MPI implementation (e.g. [MPICH2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/), [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/), [LAM-MPI](http://www.lam-mpi.org/), etc).

So, to answer your question, strictly speaking there is no such thing as an "OpenMPI application".

As for what applications use **MPI**, there are many. Here's a few:

- [AMBER](http://ambermd.org/) (Molecular Dynamics)
- [Gromacs](http://www.gromacs.org/) (Molecular Dynamics)
- [DL-POLY](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/arc/dlpoly.shtml) (molecular dynamics)
- [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/parallel/parallel-fftw.html) (for parallel Fourier transform)
- [MATLAB Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/parallel-computing/index.html)
- [FLAME](http://www.flame.ac.uk/) (Agent-based modelling)
- [CASTEP](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/arc/castep.shtml) (Materiam science)
- [POLCOMS](http://www.cse.scitech.ac.uk/arc/polcoms.shtml) (Marine Ecosystem)
- [WRF](http://www.wrf-model.org) (Weather Forecast)
- [NWCHEM](http://www.nwchem-sw.org/index.php/Main_Page) (Computational Chemistry)

... and the list goes on and on.

Comment: I mean the name of some application which is using openmpi

Comment: The point I'm making is an application uses **MPI**, it doesn't use OpenMPI (which is simply an implemenation of OpenMPI). Unless you mean [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/)?

Comment: AMBER, Gromacs is what I want. I mean OpenMPI(www.open-mpi.org)

Comment: AMBER, GRomacs, etc are parallelised using MPI. They can be run using any of the MPI implementations (MPICH2, OpenMPI, LAM-MPI, ScaliMPI, Intel MPI, ... )

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could search for MPI benchmarks. There are several popular ones such as NAS, PALLAS, SPEC, etc.